# Password salting vs. length extension attacks

Tags: passwords, hash, salt, threat-modeling

I read that when salting passwords, it is advised to use a `h(pwd||salt)` construction instead of `h(salt||pwd)`, the latter being vulnerable to a length extension attack.

What are possible scenarios in which being able to extend a salted password is useful for an attacker ?

I am aware that there are better ways of storing passwords than just salting them, though I would still like to know, supposedly in a case where only salted passwords are used, how being able to do length extension attacks is useful to an attacker.

Comment: __You should never ever use a simple hash for passwords in the first place__. And once you do proper password hashing the question gets irrelevant. See  [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am aware of that, as stated in my post. Though I would still like to know, supposedly in a case where only salted passwords are used, how being able to do length extension attacks is useful to an attacker.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not applicable at all.

Two cases;

1. Online password try with the application interface: The attacker has no control to execute a length extension attack.
2. The attackers have a write access to the server:

   To be able to execute a length extension attack on the passwords, you need to know the original passwords, too.  If a password is hashed then actually it is stored as

   `h(salt||pwd||pad1)`

   With the length extension attack, it will be

   `h(salt||pwd||pad1||extension||pad2)`

   Therefore, they need to know the original, too. **Hey wait there**, if they can access to write then they can modify it with `h(salt||password that that know)`

Length extension attacks work when the attacker can modify the message that is going to be sent or during the transmission. An example is the [Flicker API](http://netifera.com/research/flickr_api_signature_forgery.pdf)

Final note: For passwords, you need a memory-hard password hashing with calculation timing control ( possibly with iteration). The current trend is to use Argon2.